# Letter Press Effect

Tags: html, colors, css

I can't seem to get the color values/names correct so that I can get a Letter Press Effect on the text.

> To create the appearance of text that has been stamped, choose a text
>   colour that is darker than the background, and then create a 1px text
>   shadow with a 1px blur and offset it down 1px. Make the text-shadow
>   slightly lighter than the background

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
color: #222;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF;
```

So far I get only this

[image]

How would I go about

1. Finding the text colour that is darker than the background. Background color is rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.8) and text color is #222.
2. Finding the text shadow color that is ligher than the background. Background color is rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.8) and text shadow color is #FFFFFF;

I need to change the text color (currently #222) to a darker and text shadow color (currently #FFFFFF) to a lighter against a background color (currently rgba 255, 255, 255, 0.8). I can't change the background color to any other.

Have no designing skills and maybe someone would how what color values to change of the text as well as text shadow to have a letter press effect which is more obvious.

Thanks

Comment: I guess this doesn't look unreasonable: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/JPhmN/

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Thanks but it's really not that obvious. Maybe something like http://www.midwinter-dg.com/permalink-7-great-css-based-text-effects-using-the-text-shadow-property_2011-03-03.html

Comment: This looks a little better: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/JPhmN/1/ Part of the problem is your choice of background; it's hard to see the white border.

Comment: You currently have a letterpress effect, what more are you after?

Comment: Maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/JPhmN/2/

Comment: If you double up on the `text-shadow`, with your color characteristics, it helps a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/JPhmN/4/

Comment: @Jared Farrish: Ok thanks. I guess I have to live with that. Pls make an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Ok thanks. I guess I have to live with that. Pls make an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do less of a blur on the text-shadow?

You're using:

```
color: #222;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFF;
```

Use less of a blur and your text-shadow becomes more prevalent:

```
color: #222;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #FFF;
```

Blur is the third parameter in this case, which you should have a value of `0px` rather than `1px` for a more letter-press-like effect.

Comment: i found this helpfull.  http://line25.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/letterpress/demo/demo.html   color makes all the difference... you are trying to get light and shadows of this imaginary paper --- go with colors closer to the paper instead of white or black... like text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);  maybe that on one edge... and then another one on the other edge... ???  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255 .5);  ???  that way you are using the pretend paper's color ?  just an idea...

Answer (score 2):

fool around with this use of a few text-shadows ---

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/bTZs9/1/

the blur really depends on the font-size... and using rgba color helps take the guess work out of finding different tints to match the paper color...

[image]

Comment: I wanted to change the link above but it wont let me. see this one instead for future people looking this up.  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/bTZs9/

Comment: Thank you for this. It helped a lot. Can't vote it up again though.

Answer (score 0):

Color #222 is so dark. You must use to #333 or #444 to stamp ink. And the ink is not solid thing. You have to give some noise to text with like this thing : http://www.mightymeta.co.uk/demos/css-noise/

Comment: does not help much. Tried changing the font-size and font-family as well but I really cant say it looks letter press effected.

Comment: I didn't said anything about font-family or font-size?

Comment: I know you did't say anything about font-family or font-size. I was just thinking aloud. In any case I did not down vote you. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit fancy, but you could use pseudo elements:

## JSFiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Asustaba/MLEwp/
```

## CSS

```
    #stamped {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font: 3em Arial, sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    }

    #stamped:before, #text:after {
    content: attr(title);
    color: #222;
    position: absolute;
    }

    #stamped:before { top: 1px; left: 1px; }
    #stamped:after  { top: 2px; left: 2px; }
```

## HTML

```
    <h1 id="stamped" title="CATTLE FARMS">CATTLE FARMS</h1>
```